# If $|z^2-3|=3|z| $ then what is the maximum value of $|z| $ where $z$ is a complex number?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I used triangle inequality like this
$$|z^2-3|≤|z|^2+|-3|$$
$$3|z|≤|z|^2+3$$
$$0≤|z|^2-3|z|+3$$
And now let's take $|z|= w$ where $w≥0$
$$0≤w^2-3w+3$$
$$Discriminant=(-3)^2-12=-3$$
$$D<0$$
Hence the inequality is true for all real w
But $w≥0$ so it's true for all real non negative $|z|$ 
So how can there be a maximum value?
On the other hand if i use
$$||z|^2-|-3||≤|z^2-3|$$
$$||z|^2-3|≤3|z|$$
I get
$$|z|^2-|-3|≤3|z|$$ or $$|z|^2-|-3|≥-3|z|$$
The first one gives max value as $(3+✓21)/2$
The second one gives $(-3+✓21)/2$

The correct answer is $(3+✓21)/2$
But I want to know why the other two inequalities got the wrong domains.
**I don't want to know how to get the answer, i want to know why the two of the inequalities are wrong.**

Comment: It is simply $$|a|-|b|\leq |a-b|$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve $\max_{r, \theta} \{ r | |r^2 e^{i2 \theta} -3| = 3r, |\theta| \le \pi \}$ (it is straightforward to check that the constraint set is compact, so a solution exists).

Show that $|r^2 e^{i2 \theta} -3| = 3r$ is equivalent to 
$(r^2-3)^2 = r^2 ( 3+6 \cos (2 \theta))$ and $r \ge 0$.

It is clear that $r>0$ as it does not satisfy the equality so we can write the constraints
as $(r-{3 \over r})^2 = (3 +6 \cos 2 \theta)$, $r>0$. Noting that $r \mapsto (r-{3 \over r})^2$ is increasing for $r \ge \sqrt{3}$, we see that the $\max$ $r>0$ satisfies
$(r-{3 \over r})^2 = 9$, or $r^2-3r-3 = 0$. Solving gives
$r={1 \over 2} (3+\sqrt{21})$.

---

Let $F = \{ z |\  |z^2-3| = 3|z| \}$.

Let $z \in F$ then $z$ satisfies $3|z|\le |z|^2+3$. However,
$\{ z |\ 3|z|\le |z|^2+3 \} = \mathbb{C}$.

So the first inequality you derive just states that $F \subset \mathbb{C}$.

If $z \in F$ then $z$ satisfies $|z|^2-3|z|-3 \le 0$ and so we see that
$|z| \le {1\over 2} (3 + \sqrt{21})$ and since the right hand side satisfies
the constraint, we see that $z^*={1\over 2} (3 + \sqrt{21})$ is a solution.

If $z \in F$ then $z$ satisfies $|z|^2+3|z|-3 \ge 0$ and this just tells us that
$|z| \ge {1\over 2} (-3 + \sqrt{21})$.

There is no contradiction.

Comment: Kindly see the last line.

Comment: @Janstew: I added an explanation why your first inequality conclusion is incorrect. Note that $x^2-3x+3 $ has no real roots.

Comment: it has no real root that's why I stated that it's always positive for all positive values.

Comment: @Janstew: Sorry, I got distracted by work and forgot to finish. I have finished now.

Comment: How can you know that in the second inequality right hand side satisfies the constraint without putting the value in? (And what does the asterisk on z mean?)

Comment: @Janstew: Because it is one of the roots of the quadratic and $|z|^2>3$.

Comment: how to know which inequality to follow while solving such problems?

Comment: @Janstew: No recipe, unfortunately. Just experience, trail & error.

Comment: Thanks buddy for understanding what I really wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong about any of the inequalities.

What's happened with the triangle inequality is that it doesn't help any in this case since it tells you what you knew before, namely that $|z|\ge 0.$

As for the third inequality, you made a mistake somewhere. Recall that it gives us the solution $$|z|\le \frac{-3-\sqrt{21}}{2}$$ or $$|z|\ge \frac{-3+\sqrt{21}}{2}.$$ So in this case we cannot say anything about a maximum value. So this doesn't help either.

That leaves the second inequality, which gave you a maximum value.

Comment: How would we know which of the inequalities to follow?

Comment: @Janstew You can immediately see that the triangle inequality won't help you since you get $3|z|\le |z|^2+3,$ which one can see to be true for all $z.$